# Extract some letters from a string and add hyphen in Python

Tags: python, string

have files with date attached in last part of filename. Like this.

```
string = 'blablablabla_20210812.jpg'
```

I extract that data like this.

```
string[-12:][:-4]
```

I  want to add '-' between year, month and date. This is how I do.

```
string[-12:][:-4][:4] + '-' + string[-12:][:-4][4:][:2] + '-' + string[-12:][:-4][6:]
```

In my opinion, it seems like more complicated than reading machine code. Could you guys could enlighten me the ways which are more pragmatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put both indices in one square and use join function:

```
'-'.join([string[-12:-8], string[-8:-6], string[-6:-4]])
```

Also, I personally prefer to keep code readable. You can name the variables first:

```
def extractDataInfo(string):
  year, month, day = string[-12:-8], string[-8:-6], string[-6:-4]
  return '-'.join([year, month, day])
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use regular expression and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```py
import re

s = "blablablabla_20210812.jpg"

s = re.sub(r"_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.", r"_\1-\2-\3.", s)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
blablablabla_2021-08-12.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also replace the values joining the groups with `lambda`:

```py
>>> import re
>>> string = 'blablablabla_20210812.jpg'
>>> re.sub('(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})', lambda m: '-'.join(g for g in m.groups()), string)

#output: 'blablablabla_2021-08-12.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compress the `string[-12:][:-4][:4]` to `string[-12:-8]` to make it look cleaner. The code will look like this:

```
string = 'blablablabla_20210812.jpg'
print(string[-12:-8] + '-' + string[-8:-6]+ '-' + string[-6:-4])
# 2021-08-12
```

Or this if you want the text:

```
print(string[:-8] + '-' + string[-8:-6]+ '-' + string[-6:-4])
# blablablabla_2021-08-12
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution for this question will work only if you know that the file always ends with:

```
_data.extension
```

If so, the solution will be:

```
string = 'blablablabla_20210812.jpg'
s = string.replace("_", ".")
s = s.split(".")
data = s[1]
s[1] = data[:4] + "-" + data[4:6] + "-" + data[6:]
print(s[1]) # OUTPUT: 2021-08-12

# Taking all together:
print(s[0] + "_" + s[1] + "." + s[2])  # OUTPUT: blablablabla_2021-08-12.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this:

```
import datetime 
print(datetime.datetime.strptime(string[-12:-4],'%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Output:

```
'2021-08-12'
```